# A counter made in Node.js which changes its value at definite time intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, counter

I am asking help for a problem which I am not able to solve despite every effort. I am trying to make a counter. This counter is to be placed in a div under the available items on a webpage. This counter should be able to change its value at predefined values and intervals, for example, the value starts at 5,000 at then decreases by 1 after 2 seconds and then by 4 after next 5 seconds and then by 3 after next 2 seconds and then the process repeats (decreases by 1 after 2 seconds...) three or four sets of variation will be enough.
The value shown by the counter must not be affected by the number of page loads or simultaneous users, also it should remain if the user sees the page in two different browsers, it must only be shown as described above.
This counter must be capable of changing its value without needing the user to refresh the page.

Comment: This is a humongous question with at least 3 separate parts.  Consider trying to break down the problem and asking specific questions about these parts.  For example `How do I make a counter count down at specific intervals` or `How can I update information on my webpage with the user refreshing`.  Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I encourage you to follow @Brennan's suggestion and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward solution as it appears to me would be to make the timer relative to absolute time.

This means you take the time passed since an arbitrary point in time you define as the start, e.g. right now which is `var start = Date("Thu Jun 04 2015 01:46:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)")` here. You can now subtract `start` from the current time to learn how much time has passed:

```
var passedSeconds = (new Date() - start) / 1000;
```

We divide by 1000 since JS calculates with miliseconds by default.

To update the timer, do a simple

```
setInterval(function() {
     var passedSeconds = (new Date() - start) / 1000;
     var value = doCalculationForSeconds(passedSeconds);
     document.getElementById('myDisplay)'.textContent = value;
}, 1000);
```

which calls this method every second.

Lastly, you need to figure out a good way to calculate the progress. You could either run your formula in a big loop for all of passedSeconds. Or you  evaluate if you can reduce it to a single calculation step. Will depend on the exact changes in value you'll have in your final version.